# Simple Highlight Only One Element at a Time Function

Tags: javascript

I have a selected (for highlighting) class that I want to add only on one element at a time, so every time you click a new element, it adds the selected class to that and removes the selected class from any previously clicked element — no matter which.

I can only make it work if you click elements (buttons) directly next / previous to each other.

If I click on Button 1 and then e.g., Button 4, then it just keeps adding classes.

https://jsfiddle.net/vLkjovrv/1/

```
var myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.my-button');

 for (var i = 0; i < myButtons.length; i++) {

  var button = myButtons[i];

  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

   this.classList.toggle("selected");
   this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("selected");
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("selected");

});

}
```

I'm aware why the above doesn't work, I directly tell it to only address next / prev, however I've tried using if / else classList contains, !this.classList.contains, e.currentTarget in various combinations but I can't make it work.

I suppose I'm look for something like:

**if (any myButtons.classList.contains("selected")) 

remove selected 

else 

add selected**

I've spend hours searching for a vanilla JS solution, but I can only find jQuery — I want to learn plain JavaScript.

Can someone give me some pointers here? Would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Wow I got several great answers already, I wish I knew how to judge which one is “best”.

Comment: @DavidWickström solution is't the best I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way of handling this problem. First the inner forEach loop takes care of removing the "selected" class from all buttons, and then the class is added to the clicked button.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(b) {
  b.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(b) {
      b.classList.remove('selected')
    })
    b.classList.toggle('selected')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, wow there are many ways of solving this one it seems, I need to take a deeper look at forEach.call

Comment: You are most welcome. The use of forEach instead of a regular for-loop is just a matter of preference. The main point of my proposal is that you trigger a loop that removes all the classes first, before you apply it to the clicked button.

Comment: I like this approach, and I learned something new, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I've modified a bit your code. You find here the update https://jsfiddle.net/giuseppe_straziota/s6s0yb2k/

I've insert this cicle

```
for (var i = 0; i < myButtons.length; i++) {
                         var button2 = myButtons[i];
              button2.classList.remove("selected");
      }
```

Comment: Another great one, thank you! This particular one goes under the nested loop category, right? I'm trying to learn from the different solutions I've got :-)

Comment: Yes, it is. Although, it's not the more elegant :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use

```
document.querySelectorAll(".selected")
```

```js
(function() {

  var myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.my-button');

  for (var i = 0; i < myButtons.length; i++) {

    var button = myButtons[i];

    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var x = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
      if(x.length) {
       x[0].classList.remove('selected');
      }
      this.classList.toggle("selected");
      

    });
  }
})();
```

```css
.selected {
  background: darkred;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="my-button">Button 1</div>

  <div class="my-button">Button 2</div>


  <div class="my-button">Button 3</div>
  <div class="my-button">Button 4</div>

  <div class="my-button">Button 5</div>
  <div class="my-button">Button 6</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's an interesting one, what do you call this type of loop? I thought it was a nested loop first, but not sure (I'm eager to learn).

Comment: This one does not use loop. It just change the 1st element that has class 'selected'.

    x[0].classList.remove('selected');